# Tor Relay questions (equipment, router hardware, DSL)

Tags: relays, mac, routers

I would like to contribute to the cause by running a Tor Relay. After spending the last week researching, I am still unable to answer the following questions:

1. What are the MINIMUM COMPUTER requirements? May I run the relay on an older MacBook Pro? How about an older iMac? Do I need something high-end ($$$)?
2. What are the PREFERRED ROUTER requirements? Do I need to upgrade from my generic ISP router, or should I purchase something more specific to support the cause?
3. I live in the boon-docks and must connect to the Internet through DSL with the only cable/telephone company that services my area. Will a Tor Relay work with DSL service?
4. I do not have the software/hardware expertise to do this, but willing to donate equipment and time to help. Is there someone within the Tor community that can help me get things up and running?

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10234/what-is-the-most-appropriate-kind-of-hardware-to-run-a-tor-relay-on/12255

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-for-running-a-relay

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/what-are-the-best-routers-to-run-a-relay-behind?rq=1

Comment: No you don't need expensive hardware. Most routers suck, those that don't suck cost too much. Yes, it'll work on DSL. If you have specific questions about getting it up and running, check out the documentation, search on here to ask a new question if it's not a question already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it! Let's run your list step-by-step:

1. Tor's crypto is single core, sadly(until I finally debug and release my patch). So you need - basically - a dual-core CPU. One core to handle the crypto - other to do other stuff. Old Mac and iMac are OK, but be prepared for some complications compiling latest OpenSSL and Libevent on them. Minimal requirement is dual-core CPU + 512M ram. It will handle in no-GUI dedicated mode the single node of Tor fine. I've tested it on Raspberry Pi B+ - it's a singlecore, 512M RAM total, works fine!
2. Try to use OpenWRT on your router, if possible - it will give you more speed.  ADSL speeds are not a hyper-ones, so having 10Mbps down and 2Mbps up does not require much hardware in a stack. If your router can make it - it's fine!
3. Yes, asymmetric connections like DSL are not a problem at all in running Tor
4. Contact me on skype aves777 and on Facebook (https://facebook.com/avesnin) - we will bring it up!